# Object required error VBA Iserror and vlookup

Tags: vba

I am getting object required error in following line of code

```
Set Flag = "If(Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, Offset1).Value, abcd.Value, 1, False)),False,True)"

    If (Flag = True) Then
     ActiveCell.Value = "abc"
```

where abcd is a named range.
Can someone please suggest way to rectify this error?

Comment: You can't set `Flag` to a string.  However it looks like Flag might be a Boolean?  Hard to tell with so little code

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What is `Flag` defined as? Why not use VBA to handle the if statement and search?

Comment: @Gareth is right. If you start doing work in VBA, you should soon refrain from using the WorksheetFunction and use the VBA functions instead.See http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win006.htm for finding values in ranges

Answer (score 0):

I have some qualms about the vlookup function.  I don't understand everything you're trying to do, but

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, Offset1).Value, abcd.Value, 1, False)
```

looks wonky.

1. Your second term is abcd.Value.  This needs to be a range of cells.
2. Your third value is 1. The first column of a vlookup is reserved for the index, not retrievable values, so I don't think you can have the value 1 here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup()` then a non-match will result in a run-time error which you will need to trap using `On Error`.

If you instead use `Application.VLookup()` then an error value is returned in the event no match is made - you can test for this using `IsError()`

```
If IsError(Application.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, Offset1).Value, _
                                           Range("abcd"), 1, False)) Then

    ActiveCell.Value = "abc"
```